# Horizontal scrollView/UIImageView layout issue

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout

The goal: Have a scroll view that displays an array of uiimageviews (photos) that you can horizontally scroll through them

How I understand to do this: Make the frame (CGRect) of each uiimageview the height and width of the scroll view, the `y` value to 0 on each, and set the first imgViews `x` value to 0. For every imgView after that, add the width of the scrollview to the x value. In theory, this would line the imgViews (Photos) up next to each other horizontally and not allow for any vertical scrolling or zooming, purely a horizontal photo viewer.

The storyboard setup: I am creating my scrollview in a xib file (It’s a custom uiCollectionViewCell), with these constraints:
— Top space to cell (0)
— Trailing space to cell (0)
— Leading space to cell (0)
— Height of 400
— Bottom space to a view (0)
 —— (See Below for img)

Laying out the UIImgViews:

```
func layoutScrollView() {
    for (index, img) in currentImages.enumerate() {
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(index) * scrollView.bounds.width, y: CGFloat(0), width: scrollView.bounds.width, height: scrollView.bounds.height))
        imgView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        imgView.image = img
        scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: imgView.frame.width * CGFloat(index), height: scrollView.bounds.height)
        scrollView.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

My suspicion:   I suspect the issue is stemming from the auto layout constraints i’ve specified, but (considering Im asking a SO question) not sure

If there is a better way to do this (really the correct way) please let me know! I have been trying to wrap my head around this for a few days now.

I appreciate all responses! Thanks for reading
[image: Auto layout constraints]

**EDIT #1**
I tried paulvs approach of setting setNeedsLayout & layoutIfNeeded before the "for" loop, and still no luck. Here is (out of three images selected) the second photo displaying. It seems that both the first and second photos are way longer than the content view and that would move the middle view over (Squished).

[image: Middle of scroll view (Photo #2 out of 3)]

Comment: IMO, if you have to show horizontally scrollable images then you should go for UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling. It would be super easy as compare to using UIScrollView.

Comment: I see your point, but the point at hand was the issue that this is not fitting on my scroll view. I do think that is something that could potentially happen in the future, though. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine except for a few details (that may be causing the problem):

1. Add:

   ```
   view.setNeedsLayout()
   view.layoutIfNeeded()
   ```

   before accessing the `scrollView`'s frame (a good place would be before the for-loop).
   This is because when using Autolayout, if you access a view's frame before the layout engine has performed a pass, you will get incorrect frames sizes/positions.
2. Remove these lines from inside the for-loop:

   ```
   scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: imgView.frame.width * CGFloat(index), height: scrollView.bounds.height)
   scrollView.setNeedsLayout()
   ```

   and place this line after (outside) the for loop:

   ```
   scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: imgView.frame.width * CGFloat(currentImages.count), height: scrollView.bounds.height)
   ```